# Trigger to backup a registry after delete it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering if there is a way to backup a registry within another table after a DELETE statement is executed.

for example if I have the table 'employee' and I execute:
`delete from employee where idEmp=1`

is there any way to insert the data of that employee into another table called 'employeeBackup'(for example) using a trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a DELETE trigger.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Make sure in your trigger that you reference the deleted virtual table and avoid using any variables because triggers fire once per operation, not once per row.

Here is a basic template you could use.

```
create trigger MyDeleteTrigger on employee FOR DELETE as
    set nocount on;

    insert employeeBackup
    (
        Column1,
        Column2
    )
    select Colum1
        , Column2
    from deleted
```